# I want to change the color of ``` titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge```

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, color-scheme

I want to set the text style using `titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,` in my app bar but i need to change de color and i don't now how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you stack the `Theme.of(context)` and `copyWith` methods, each time making one change. This can get pretty verbose if you have a lot of things to change. For example, to make a titleLarge with error color

```
Text(
    'ERROR',
         style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
         color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error),
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this, More about [design/themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,// appBar background color
              titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            )),
    home: ... (),
  );
}
```

Comment: I Already found the way to do it `Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge?.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface),`

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't seem to address the OP's question, which is answered in the OP's comment.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich  *doesn't seem* doesn't actually tell it is right/wrong, There are n ways to solve a issue, if you may give try by implanting and let's use know if it actually failed

Comment: He asked how to use titleLarge and set the color. How is that related to backgroundColor or appBarTheme? @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Well if you look at the next line you can see `titleTextStyle`